# How to access to a function from another file, in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to get access to a function from different file for example:

```
router
     -users.js
     -posts.js
```

I want to have access to the function that is located in the **users.j**s file

from **posts.js**

How can I do that?

here is the function in **user.js file**

```
  const writeFileToFolder = (file, userId, res, session) => {
  console.log("My session and path", userId, session);
    }
```

Here is what I've tried **posts.js**. but when I did a consoel.log, the result was undefined.

```
  const {
  writeFileToFolder,
  file,
  userId,
  res,
  session,
} = require("./Upload");
```

**#Update:**
I just separate the file and now the function that I want to have access to is in one file. I did it like this.

```
  exports.writeFileToFolderAccess = (file, userId, res, session) => {
  const filePath = `/imageUpload/${userId}/${file.name}`;
  console.log("the session", filePath);
  console.log("My session and path", userId, session);

  file.mv(filePath, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      session.uploadedFilePath = filePath;
      res.json({ status: "ok", message: "File uploaded" });
    }
  });
};
```

**and in the post.js I have import like this.**

```
  const acessFile = ({
  writeFileToFolderAccess,
  session,
} = require("../fileStructure/AccessFile"));
```

and finally, this is how I call the function in posts.js

```
acessFile.writeFileToFolderAccess(session);
```

But now it gives an error

```
 server\fileStructure\AccessFile.js:2
  const filePath = `/imageUpload/${userId}/${file.name}`;
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

any sugesstion?

Comment: Can you share more code examples for clearer understanding?

Comment: Add `extports.writeFileToFolder = writeFileToFolder` at the bottom

Comment: Ok. I do have a module export like this.
module.exports = router;
but in the user.js i have many functions/ i only need to have access to this function.

const writeFileToFolder = (file, userId, res, session) => {
  const filePath = `/imageUpload/${userId}/${file.name}`;
  console.log("the session", filePath);
  file.mv(filePath, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      session.uploadedFilePath = filePath;
      res.json({ status: "ok", message: "File uploaded" });
    }
  });
};

Comment: I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the export before the function declaration in the user.js file.

```
export const writeFileToFolder = (file, userId, res, session) => {
console.log("My session and path", userId, session);
}
```

Comment: The OP is using CommonJS-style imports (`require()` & `module.exports`), not Modules (`import` & `export`). This _would be_ a correct answer if they were using the latter.

Comment: Hey, I've imported, but still, I am getting undefined.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated quesiton. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the function from another file, you need to export it from the given file. This is what you need to do:

**User.js**

```
export.writeFileToFolder = (file, userId, res, session) => {
  console.log("My session and path", userId, session);
}
```

However, you could also export it at the end of the file like this:

```
const writeFileToFolder = (file, userId, res, session) => {
  console.log("My session and path", userId, session);
}

module.exports = writeFileToFolder;
```

**posts.js**

```
const user = require("./User.js");
// Now you can access the function. 
user.writeFileToFolder();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, yes did what you said, but now i have another error. if you check the update, in my quesion

Comment: @John Alright, please provide a bigger snippet of the code where you try to access the file. I would like to see where the variables comes from etc :) If not, I will not be able to figure out what's wrong

Comment: In this file, called Post.js
i want to acces this fucntion (writeFileToFolderAccess(file, userId, session);
) from this file User.js

if you take a look at the updated question, you will code how I implement this writeFileToFolderAccess() function in user.js. 

But, when I called the function it gave some errors, that I added them in the updated quesion. thanks

Comment: @John Aah okey, i see the issue. The function has the parameters ```(file, userId, res, session)```. However, when you call the function, you only pass the session object, ```acessFile.writeFileToFolderAccess(session);```. You need to pass all the variables that the function requires =)

Comment: thanks a lot, should i import them as well all the parameters?

Comment: @John It's like any other function call, just provide the parameters that the function requires =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try them one by one in console.log?

console.log(userId);
console.log(session);

What do you get then?

Comment: No i tried like this 

console.log("My session and path", file, userId, res, session);


and i got undefined for all of them.

Comment: @John Could you try console.log for them separately. A little more code will help us understand more. Have you exported your function?

Comment: Hey, Yes I did but still it give undefined.
and also I just updated my question. take a look at #update, thanks for your time

Comment: i am uploading the file, so it should be the file name, though it is working very well.

Comment: const filePath = `/imageUpload/${userId}/${file}`;  Remove file.name and just use file. If you want the base name of the file, use  var file = path.basename(filePath); I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i didn't get with this part: path.basename(filePath);   where should i add this ? thanks

Comment: You can use that only if you need the name of the file. You don't need to add it if you have no need for it.

Comment: AHHHHH, i see, no actually i do need them

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.